# Using nestR package in R for finding potential bird nests with the use of spatial data

Tags: r, dplyr

As nestR package (picardis/nestR) requires I have a csv file with 4 columns:

- burst: which is always one
- date: POSIXt format
- long: longitude
- lat: latitude

It is a file with random bird locations around an area and with the use of nestR I would like to find possible nests

```
setwd("I:/R TESTS")

library(nestR)
library(dplyr)
data(X154)
X154 <-read.csv("X154.csv")
```

find_nest function worked and gave me a list with 2 dataframes as expected (nests, visits)

```
ws_output_1 <- find_nests(gps_data = X154,
                          sea_start = "05-02",
                          sea_end = "06-01",
                          nest_cycle = 30,
                          buffer = 40,
                          min_pts = 2,
                          min_d_fix = 1,
                          min_consec = 2,
                          min_top_att = 1,
                          min_days_att = 1,
                          discard_overlapping = FALSE)
```

the next function explore_nests should open shiny and be like the uploaded image, instead everything is blank, when I try to manually set the input parameters (in the burst tab I cannot choose anything) and hit find nests

```
explore_nests(ws_output_1)
```

this error appears

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4402
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"
  146: dplyr::filter
  145: %>%
  144: eventReactiveValueFunc
  100: nests
   99: renderDataTable
   98: func
   85: renderFunc
   84: output$nest_results
    3: runApp
    2: print.shiny.appobj
    1: <Anonymous>
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"
  146: dplyr::filter
  145: %>%
  144: eventReactiveValueFunc
  100: nests
   99: renderDataTable
   98: func
   85: renderFunc
   84: output$nest_results
    3: runApp
    2: print.shiny.appobj
    1: <Anonymous>
```

After Phil's suggestion I tried

```
explore_nests(ws_output_1[[1]])
```

and now it gives me a new error

```
Warning: Error in check_input: Data does not include required fields or column names are different.
         Check that gps_data includes burst, date, long, and lat.
  147: stop
  146: check_input
  145: find_nests
  144: eventReactiveValueFunc
  100: nests
   99: renderDataTable
   98: func
   85: renderFunc
   84: output$nest_results
    3: runApp
    2: print.shiny.appobj
    1: <Anonymous>
```

But the gps_data file (X154) has the exact 4 columns (No spelling error or something).

Any ideas please?
Thank you

Comment: Try `explore_nests(ws_output_1[[1]])`

Comment: I now get a different error

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
I should do the search in the the data file
explore_nests(X154)

Thanks for your time everyone!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).